# Is it possible to find all integer functions which satisfy $f(m!+n!)\mid f(m!)+f(n!)$ and $m+n \mid f(m)+f(n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, multiplicative-number-theory

I'm interesting to know more about multiplicative property of integer functions then I'd like to ask this humble question:

**Question:**
Is it possible to find all integer  functions which satisfy $f(m!+n!)\mid f(m!)+f(n!)$ and $m+n \mid f(m)+f(n)$?

**Note:** the symbol | meant divides

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you give any context why you are interested in this question? In the present form the question looks suspiciously like a competition problem.

Comment: ok , really i 'd like to study and know more about multiplicative integer function and to study it's periodicity

Comment: It is tempting to say that this looks like an attempt to tempt people into solving a contest problem for you. Instead, I ask "What have you tried?" .  Gerhard "So, What Have You Tried?" Paseman, 2016.10.29.

Comment: I guess the question is about two classes of integers: 1) all integer functions which satisfy $f(n! + m!)|f(n!)+f(m!)$ AND 2) all integer functions which satisfy $f(n + m)| f(n) +f(m)$ .

Comment: I think it's work with  f(n)=n!

Comment: I assume you mean $f(n)=n$ because $f(n)=n!$ does not work.

Comment: f(0!+1!)| f(0!)+f(1! ) and 0+1 | f(0)+f(1) , yes you are right , f(n)=n not n!

Answer (score -3):

When $n=m$,
$f(n)=kn$
then $f(m!)+f(n!)=k(m!+n!)=f(m!+n!)$

Therefore, $f(n)=kn$.

Comment: Why is $k$ constant?

Comment: It doesn't need constant.

Comment: You are treating it as constant when you write $f(m!) + f(n!) = k(m! + n!)$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki, you must remember that you are in interactive website with professional mathematicians !!!!!

Comment: @L Spice I removed constant solution. see log.

Comment: f(n)=n is not all integer solution.